Grid with minimal line length density that intersects all unit-length line segments
I was looking at a sewer grate (cap with grid) on the pavement and started thinking about the following question: How can we design a grate that uses the least material while ensuring that my phone/bank card doesn't go through the gaps?
In mathematical terms, consider an infinitely large, periodic grid. The grid lines can be straight or smoothly curved. Define the line length density of the grid as the total length of the gridlines in a large region divided by the area of this region. (More rigorously, this is the limit of the quotient as the region grows indefinitely large.)
The grid must satisfy the condition that it intersects every line segment of unit length, regardless of orientation or position.
The question is:
What grid configuration minimizes the line length density while meeting this requirement?
How can we prove that this configuration is optimal?
As a starting example, consider the "square pattern" grid, consisting of equally spaced horizontal and vertical lines. To ensure the requirement is satisfied, the spacing between lines must be at most
$1/\sqrt{2}$. In this case, the line length density is $2\sqrt{2}$.

How do you know that any such minimal configuration would be unique?

@PaulTanenbaum I'm not sure if such a minimal configuration is unique or not. I hope it at least exists.

I guess you suppose the diameter of the phone is 1, since scaling it change the density. The density of the hexagonal grid is $4\sqrt{3}/3$
